# Typescript optional function truthy check

Tags: typescript, optional-parameters, truthiness

I think I'm missing something basic on how you can check for a truthy value with && in Typescript.

Why can props.function still be undefined in test1 and has to be checked like I did in test2.

```js
import React from "react";

interface PropsModel {
    label?: string
    function?: Function,
}

function test1(props: PropsModel) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.label && <p>{props.label}</p>} // props.label is checked for undefined
            {props.function && <button onClick={() => props.function()}>Dummy button</button>} // props.function is not checked for undefined
        </div>
    )
}

function test2(props: PropsModel) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.label && <p>{props.label}</p>} // props.label is checked for undefined
            {props.function && <button onClick={() => {if (props.function) props.function()}}>Dummy button</button>} // props.function is checked for undefined
        </div>
    )
}
```

EDIT 1: Added Link to playground

Link to [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgAUcwBnAWQgBMkANnADe5OOLgCUAI0EB%20AFxwOMKDQDmYiZgCu1DMAjVFcAGJ6DRgDTkAvpV36Yh6nDoqAjAAow7DkrYITh5%20AQBKES1xIhgdKFcvKIlxAB5eYAA3AD4k5OThXyCOADopWSEAMgq4FLAsgr9SmUFbFIB6Ots4Nra4Qs4m8rhgDjg0AAskNABrJF44TGg4PX5MGjncvPEGouLHS1cqmukdGBgjOCMAYQFgGYBeYS8I%206y%20xv3nI2fbLIARHQgEAATzgJzORna4PO1CyXR6712nxcw1G1Ag8AmU1m80WUGW1FW614m1SbXS2SSYTsDgsX1c7hgACYfH4An4QoIIqJkjE4glSTUKTktlsdgMyoI4EdavV%20iVJQJWh04d1evLBlKRmNJjM5gsliskGtqBtRXlxSVkRcZdCLtdbg8ni83sJgJg4KykXSXBENdbqD9fgCgaC7dQoacYaqEf6fRdtVi9bjDYTjcTBe1hVSaUA)

Answer (score 3):

I am by no means an expert on this matter of TS as I too have wondered this. My assumption so far is to do with the level of "scope". Aka the `onClick` function is of a different scope to your Component. If you're 100% sure that the function will exist within the OnClick you can do either of the below.

```
import React from "react";

export type Function = () => void;

export type Input = {
    label?: string;
    function?: Function;
}

function test1(props: Input) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.label && <p>{props.label}</p>} // props.label is checked for undefined
            {props.function && <button onClick={() => (props.function as Function)()}>Dummy button</button>} // props.function is not checked for undefined
        </div>
    )
}
```

or simply

```
import React from "react";

interface PropsModel {
    label?: string
    function?: Function,
}

function test1(props: PropsModel) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.label && <p>{props.label}</p>} // props.label is checked for undefined
            {props.function && <button onClick={() => props.function!()}>Dummy button</button>} // props.function is not checked for undefined
        </div>
    )
}
```

A `!` has been added to the `{props.function && <button onClick={() => props.function!()}>Dummy button</button>}` line here. `!` simply tells TS that you are 100% sure that the optional type will definitely exist at this point.

Comment: Didn't know that "!" existed. Good to know, thanks! The scope hypothesis could be correct. I'll wait to see if somebody else can confirm that and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `function` property is optional. hence to use such property we must use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

What you need to do is

```
function test1(props: PropsModel) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.label && <p>{props.label}</p>}
            {props.function && <button onClick={() => props.function?.()}>Dummy button</button>} // props.function is checked for undefined then it will be called
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note that to use optional chaining your typescript version must be `typescript >= 3.7`

Comment: But shouldn't `props.function &&` make sure that the function is not undefined and thus making optional chaining unnecessary?

Comment: yes, you are right but in this case we are only using optional chaining to avoid typescript error

Comment: So you mean it's a faulty implementation in typescript? And shouldn't actually happen?